# How to use Special Characters (|&|) in Exchange Transportation Rules?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, microsoft-exchange

I am trying to add a new transportation rule to an Exchange 2016 server. The rule should effect all mails with the following character set in the title: `|&|`

I used 'If the title contains one of the following words' and added the string `|&|` there . Unfortunately it does not work. When I use only `&` the rule works.

Should I use maybe  `\` or `"` like in some programming languages? All I tried did work work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! One have to use the pattern matching, not the string matching and escape the `|` with `\`. The resulting expression is `^(\|&\|)`